# Extracting list from string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python and facing problem to extract specific list object from string which has that list.

Here is my list object within a string.

```
input = "[[1,2,3],[c,4,r]]"
```

I need output like this.

```
output = [[1,2,3],[c,4,r]]
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Notice that `ast.literal_eval` will yield an error if `c` and `r` are nor surrounded by quotes

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
   import ast
   input = "[[1,2,3],['c',4,'r']]"
   output = ast.literal_eval(input)
   output
=> [[1, 2, 3], ['c', 4, 'r']]
```

If you actually meant for `c` and `r` to just be the current values of the variables `c` and `r` rather than the literals `'c'` and `'r'`, you'd need to use `eval`, which is rather unsafe, but otherwise works the same way.

Comment: This works on python 3.8 also

Answer (score 2):

if `ast.literal_eval` is not sufficient and `c` and `r` are meant to be non-trivial data objects that should be interpreted, you might consider using `asteval` (https://github.com/newville/asteval).  It can handle evaluating python strings beyond literal strings, including its own symbol table, and avoiding many of the known exploits with using `eval()`.

`asteval` works like a sand-boxed mini-interpreter with a simple, flat namespace.  You would have to add values for `c` and `r` to the asteval interpreter, but an example might be:

```
from asteval import Interpreter
aeval = Interpreter()
aeval('c = 299792458.0')   # speed of light?
aeval('r = c/(2*pi)')      # radius of a circle of circumference c?
                           # note that pi and many other numpy
                           # symbols and functions are built in
input_string = "[[1,2,3],[c,4,r]]"

out = aeval(input_string)
print(out)
```

which will give

```
[[1, 2, 3], [299792458.0, 4, 47713451.59236942]]
```

Alternatively, you could have  set `c` directly from Python with

```
aeval.symtable['c'] = 299792458.0
```

There are many known-to-be-unsafe things that `asteval` refuses to do, but there are also many things it can do that `ast.literal_eval` cannot.  Of course, if you're accepting code from user input, you should be very careful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module literal_eval method for a safer eval

```
import ast
input = "[[1,2,3],['c',4,'r']]"
output= ast.literal_eval(input)
print(output)
#[[1, 2, 3], ['c', 4, 'r']]
```

This code is tested in Python 3.6. It works even in 2.7 also.

Answer (score 0):

I use the pandas function 'read_json' to interpret data structures stored as a string.
In this example you can use typ = 'series' to interpret the structure as a pandas series and then change it back into a list:

```
input = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
pd.read_json(input, typ = 'series').to_list()
```

However, for some reason it only works with numeric content, not with your example of a list containing numbers and characters.

Answer (score -2):

**Never use input as variable name , it's a keyword in python :**

You can  use numpy :

```
import numpy as np

user_input = "[[1,2,3],[c,4,r]]"

print(np.array(user_input))
```

output:

```
[[1,2,3],[c,4,r]]
```